# Banshee 14.04 duplicate song detector extension

Tags: 14.04, music, banshee

Hi can anyone tell me how to install the duplcate song detector extension in banshee on 14.04?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried installing it several times without any success. I think the extension is badly outdated and no longer works. I would love to be proven wrong on this point, but it has never worked for me.

Comment: yea I haven't gotten it to work either. thanks.